# how do "strip_tags" with domxpath in php

Tags: php, html, strip-tags, domxpath

I'm working with a domxpath object and want to remove tags in the same way as strip_tags. Eventually I came up with this:

```
function strip_node(&$node)
{
    $node_list = array();
    foreach ($node->childNodes as $child)
    {
        $node->parentNode->insertBefore($child->cloneNode(true),$node);
    }
    $node->parentNode->removeChild($node);
}
```

But when I ran a query and tried to remove all the nodes it failed:

```
$matches = $xPath->query( "//div" );
foreach ($matches as $match)
{
    strip_node($match);
}
```

This is obviously because $matches is a list of the original nodes, but as I strip them out, and daughter nodes are being replaced with new.

So what can I do to get the functional equivalent of strip_tags?

Comment: If you just want to strip ALL tags, then don't even bother with this complicated business, just use innerText: $node->textContent is ALL of the text from child nodes, with the tags stripped out. you can't strip_tags on a node anyways. The node may represent html/xml, but it's not a plain string, which is what strip_tags is expecting.